# Add animation to jQuery function Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My Question** is how to add some animation to countdown timer, what I mean I need to add some animations Every time calling Function Interval() like This:
[youtube Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9fnvhcWPRo)

---

### **Second problem:**

How to add Background to Canvas?

Do I have to use another Canvas like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvasSeconds" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasBackground" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

Or is there another way to do that:

[image]

```js
(function($) {
  var date = new Date("2017-01-30");
  jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
    var settings = {
      'date': null
    };
    if (options) {
      $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    this_sel = $(this);
    /*Canvas JavaScript*/
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var canvas3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 70;


    var sec_arc_end = 0,
      min_arc_end = 0,
      hour_arc_end = 0,
      day_arc_end = 0;

    function count_exec() {
      eventDate = Date.parse(date) / 1000;
      currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
      if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
        callback.call(this);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

      days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

      seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
      hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
      seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
      minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds -= minutes * 60;

      // seconds arc canvas...................
      context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      sec_arc_end = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10472));
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + sec_arc_end, false);
      context.lineWidth = 8;
      context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context.stroke();
      // minutes arc canvas...................
      context1.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      min_arc_end = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.10471));
      context1.beginPath();
      context1.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + min_arc_end, false);
      context1.lineWidth = 8;
      context1.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context1.stroke();
      // hours arc canvas...................
      context2.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      hour_arc_end = ((24 - hours) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));
      context2.beginPath();
      context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
      context2.lineWidth = 8;
      context2.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context2.stroke();
      // days arc canvas...................
      context3.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      hour_arc_end = ((days) * parseFloat((0.10471) * 2));
      context3.beginPath();
      context3.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
      context3.lineWidth = 8;
      context3.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context3.stroke();
      // add 0 value to left of value
      if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
        this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
        this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
        this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
        this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
      }
    }
    count_exec();
    interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);


  };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#countdown").countdown({
      date: "6 january 2017 7:15:00"
    },
    function() {
      $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
    }
  );

})
```

```css
#countdown {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.countdown-container {
  width: 24%;
  height: 97%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0099FF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
#countdown .countdown-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.30% 0.5% 0.30% 0.5%;
}
#countdown .countdown-container .contents {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size-adjust: 0.58;
}
.contents div {
  font-size: 28px;
}
.contents span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-container">

    <div class="contents">
      <div class="secs">
        00
      </div>
      <span>Seconds</span>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

  </div>
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="mins">
        00
      </div>
      <span>Minutes</span>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="hours">
        00
      </div>
      <span>Hours</span>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="days">
        00
      </div>
      <span>Days</span>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: About animating text, you'll have to keep a temp div and use css/jQuery animation over it.

Comment: Thank you, I checked this JSFiddle, But this is not what I want please review my question:
first i need to animate text every time changed 
second i need to add another canvas as background

Comment: Hope this help: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/arc1hwo4/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the one you expect :)

```js
(function($) {
  var date = new Date("2017-01-30");
  jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
    var settings = {
      'date': null
    };
    if (options) {
      $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    this_sel = $(this);
    /*Canvas JavaScript*/
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var canvas3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 70;


    var sec_arc_end = 0,
      min_arc_end = 0,
      hour_arc_end = 0,
      day_arc_end = 0;

    function count_exec() {
      eventDate = Date.parse(date) / 1000;
      currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
      if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
        callback.call(this);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

      days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

      seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
      hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
      seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
      minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds -= minutes * 60;

      // seconds arc canvas...................
      context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      sec_arc_end = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10472));
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + sec_arc_end, false);
      context.lineWidth = 8;
      context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context.stroke();
      // minutes arc canvas...................
      context1.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      min_arc_end = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.10471));
      context1.beginPath();
      context1.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + min_arc_end, false);
      context1.lineWidth = 8;
      context1.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context1.stroke();
      // hours arc canvas...................
      context2.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      hour_arc_end = ((24 - hours) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));
      context2.beginPath();
      context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
      context2.lineWidth = 8;
      context2.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context2.stroke();
      // days arc canvas...................
      context3.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      hour_arc_end = ((days) * parseFloat((0.10471) * 2));
      context3.beginPath();
      context3.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
      context3.lineWidth = 8;
      context3.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context3.stroke();
      // add 0 value to left of value
      if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
        this_sel.find('#days #old').text(days);
        this_sel.find('#days #new').text(days);
        this_sel.find('#hours #old').text(hours);
        this_sel.find('#hours #new').text(hours);
        this_sel.find('#mins #old').text(minutes);
        this_sel.find('#mins #new').text(minutes);
        this_sel.find('#secs #old').text(seconds);
        this_sel.find('#secs #new').text(seconds);

        if (seconds == 59) {
          this_sel.find('#mins').addClass("animate");
        } else if (seconds == 58) {
          this_sel.find('#mins').removeClass("animate");
        }
        if (minutes == 59 && seconds == 59) {
          this_sel.find('#hours').addClass("animate");
        } else if (seconds == 58) {
          this_sel.find('#hours').removeClass("animate");
        }
        if (hours == 23 && minutes == 59 && seconds == 59) {
          this_sel.find('#days').addClass("animate");
        } else if (seconds == 58) {
          this_sel.find('#days').removeClass("animate");
        }

      }
    }
    count_exec();
    interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);


  };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#countdown").countdown({
      date: "6 january 2017 7:15:00"
    },
    function() {
      $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
    }
  );

})
```

```css
#countdown {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.countdown-container {
  width: 24%;
  height: 97%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0099FF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
#countdown .countdown-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.30% 0.5% 0.30% 0.5%;
}
#countdown .countdown-container .contents {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size-adjust: 0.58;
}
.contents {
  position: absolute;
}
.contents div {
  position: relative;
}
#secs #old {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  opacity: 0;
  //transform: rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
  animation: rotate_old 900ms infinite;
  animation-delay: 45ms;
}
#secs #new {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  //transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  animation: rotate_new 950ms infinite;
  animation-delay: 50ms;
}
#old {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
}
#new {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.animate #old {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  opacity: 0;
  // transform: rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
  animation: rotate_old 900ms infinite;
  animation-delay: 45ms;
}
.animate #new {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  animation: rotate_new 950ms infinite;
  animation-delay: 50ms;
}
#old {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  //transition: transform 800ms,opacity 700ms,color 400ms,filter 400ms;

}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
@keyframes rotate_new {
  0% {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate_old {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg) scale(2);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0% {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.5);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-container">

    <div class="contents">
      <div id="secs">
        <div id="old"></div>
        <div id="new"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="degree">Seconds</div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

  </div>
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="contents">
      <div id="mins">
        <div id="old"></div>
        <div id="new"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="degree">Minutes</div>

    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="contents">
      <div id="hours">
        <div id="old"></div>
        <div id="new"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="degree">Hours</div>

    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="contents">
      <div id="days">
        <div id="old"></div>
        <div id="new"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="degree">Days</div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I want to do already, but there are simple problem that in your code there are some delay you can compare the Link video above and your code

Comment: another problem that when i changed the radius of circle, could you help me please, and explain why that is happen?

Comment: also there are bug with circular of days that this circular must divide by 365 pieces :) because is the number of days in years is 365 days

Comment: yes i know that i just given you the way of implementing the animations , you have to work to change code based on your need.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me, please if you change the radius of circle, The problem will appear.
second circular of days that this circular must divide by 365 pieces

Answer (score -2):

Within the  give the progress class
div class="progress"
div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
div
Which may archive your goal.